# How to resolve error when trying to open Windows Display Settings?

Tags: windows-10-upgrade, windows-10

After I [finally managed to upgrade](https://superuser.com/q/946836/11720) from Windows 8.1 to Windows 10, everything seems to run smooth except one thing:

If I right click on the desktop and select "Display settings" I get an error message

> "The operating system cannot run ms-settings:display"

On my German Windows 10 this looks like:

[image]

Beside [this thread on the Microsoft forums](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/insider/forum/insider_wintp-insider_desktop/windows-10-build-10130-start-run-url-the-operating/f424018e-95ff-425a-95fb-ebc6f0413367?auth=1) which suggests to create a new profile (which I want to avoid) I found no solution.

**My question:**

Do you have any idea how to resolve this issue?

**Update 1:**

It happens for other items, too like

- `ms-settings:notifications`
- `ms-settings:personalization-background`

**Update 2:**

As pointed out, this seems to (also) be a general problem with URL protocol handling in Windows Explorer.

Doing a <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd> and typing "http://www.google.com" does result in the same error.

Also, clicking links in HTML emails in Microsoft Outlook 2013 results in an error message:

> Something unexpected went wrong with this URL:
>
> "http://www.google.com". The operating system cannot run %1.

Comment: One suggestion was that the installation is corrupt and that a re-install of the update or a clean install of the PC might help.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I uninstalled IE developer channel and it started working for me

Comment: That's incredible awesome! I tried that too, and after a reboot, it worked. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Ha. Some people here don't have IE Dev Channel and had fixed the problem by installing it then uninstalling it...

Comment: Not sure about others, but in my case it did help to install and uninstall (used Win8.1 distributive from http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43359). I did had the Dev Channel installed at the Win10 upgrade time and then removed it. I guess it has not been removed completely.

Comment: I had multiple problems after my Windows 10 update:
- Clicking on links in Outlook shows the error message "The operating system cannot run %1"
- I wasn't able to open zip files in Windows Explorer. If I used the extract menu I got the same error message and the error code 0x800700B6

Both problems were gone after uninstalling Internet Explorer developer channel(!)

Answer (score 4):

You can fix it by editing the registry.

1. Type Win+R, then regedit
2. Browse to key: *Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\ms-settings*
3. Make sure you have this:

   ```
   .--------------.--------.-----------------.
   |    Name      |  Type  |      Data       |
   :--------------+--------+-----------------:
   | (Default)    | REG_SZ | URL:ms-settings |
   :--------------+--------+-----------------:
   | URL Protocol | REG_SZ |                 |
   '--------------'--------'-----------------'
   ```

If not:

- remove all sub-keys below ms-settings.
- remove all other values in ms-settings.
- add missing values (right-click, new "String Value")

Works for Windows 10 (1803). May work for other versions too.

The result should look like this:
[image: What you must get]

Comment: This doesn't seem to work for me in build 1809, unfortunately. :(

Comment: I was, however, able to fix the issue by using System Restore.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. I haven't upgraded yet to 1809...

Comment: Thank you for this solution it worked. I searched through 15 websites and google search results before finding your solution. Everyone else made irrelevant suggestions such as system restore, sfc /scannow and generic answers. Yours works. 100%

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me because something disabled my **Connected Devices Platform Service**.

To enable it, go to Start and type "services.msc", press Enter.  Look down the list for "Connected Devices Platform Service" and double-click it, then you'll be able to click "Start".