# Windows 10 update: 0xC1900101 - 0x3000D, FIRST_BOOT and MIGRATE_DATA

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-update, updates, setup

I am currently encountering some problems related to the Windows 10 15025 Insider update. My testing machine has been stuck on 14393.187 for some months because every time Windows Update tries to install the latest build, the computer reboots, does its work and at exactly 71% the screen freezes. I tried to let it work overnight, but even after 9 hours it's still frozen. After rebooting the computers, it restores the previous version and shows me this screen:

[image: Windows 10 installation failure dialog]

I have disabled my antivirus, installed the latest drivers for my GPU (GTX 760), and unplugged all USB devices (except keyboard and mouse). I have also tried the instructions in [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/947332/316821), but it didn't work.

The above message only shows when installing using the ISO and using the Upgrade button (installing it with Windows Update doesn't give any information about what failed). There is nothing in the Event Log either.

Does anyone have any hints on how I could install that update, preferably without reinstalling Windows?

Comment: Did you eventually solve this? My impression is that such problems are M$'s way of obsoleting old PCs. E.g. on an old laptop no Windows 10 kernel newer than 1809 boots (1903 and onward all fail in with same error code and minidump that is not even saved, making even debugging the issue hard https://superuser.com/questions/1566284/where-does-panther-save-its-safe-os-minidumps).

Comment: @Fizz I didn't, I eventually gave up and reinstalled the OS :/

Answer (score 1):

Solved error 0xC1900101 - 0x3000D
I've been trying to solve this error 0XC1900101-0x3000D since months, even the Microsoft technicians were not able to solve it. Just a small thing solved this problem. Download the .iso file of the latest version, DISCONNECT your internet connection, and run the iso file. It will ask wheather to install the upgrade (recommended), or install it offline(other option). Don't choose the recommended one, instead select the 2nd option. You can keep your files, no need to format every drive, just the drive where the windows is installed. Then proceed with the rest of the steps. You can upgrade rest of the system file after the windows is installed. My Windows 10 is now running perfectly fine. I can upgrade the system, upgrade the drivers, connect any mobile, work my touchpad scroll, which all were not working earlier.
I've tried the iso file, mayB this method applies to Media creation tool also.

By the way, i first restored my lappy to windows 7 and then tried to use the iso file, but it was still showing the same error. Then i tried working it offline and it worked. So i guess i didn't had to revert it back to win 7 so as to make it work.

Hope this helps you all :)

Comment: Wait a minute, that 2nd option you're talking about is the "clean install" one?

Comment: wait a minute, "install it offline"...."no need to format every drive, just the drive where the windows is installed"....so you mean all apps/user accounts are lost if everything is on C:. That's a dangerous recommendation.

Answer (score 0):

Microsoft [explained the error:](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/itpro/windows/deploy/resolve-windows-10-upgrade-errors)

> **Code** 0xC1900101 - 0x3000D
>
> **Cause** Installation failed during the FIRST_BOOT phase while attempting the MIGRATE_DATA operation. This can occur due to a problem
>   with a display driver.

And this is what Microsoft suggest to fix the error:

> Disconnect all peripheral devices that are connected to the system,
>   except for the mouse, keyboard and display. Update or uninstall the
>   display driver.

Comment: I already did that (update, uninstall, etc), as I said in the question.

Comment: remove the nvidia driver so that you use the **Microsoft Basic Display Adapter**

Comment: It didn't work.

Comment: share the hidden folder *C:\$Windows.~BT\Sources\panther\* as zip on onedrive. I'll ask my Microsoft contacts for help.

Comment: here it is https://1drv.ms/u/s!Anv1MZa-OHvaom0r9zpvPYtfF_m6

Comment: my contact wants that you use the feedback hub app to create an issue about it and share the log there, too. Next post the share link to this feedback here so tat I can send it to Microsoft.

Comment: I created an issue on the feedback hub app, now what do I do?

Comment: when you created the entry, there is a share button (https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/5749744/Bilder/superuser/share.png) to generate a share link. post this link here, so I can send this to Microsoft, so my contact can see the issue in detail

Comment: here is the link: https://aka.ms/Byi8p7

Comment: thanks, I submitted the link. Also try the 15031 ISOs: http://winaero.com/blog/windows-10-build-15031-iso-images/ maybe the issue is already fixed in a newer build

Comment: I can't use that, those ESD files are in English and my Windows is in French

Comment: ok. Wait for the next official ISO from Microsoft.