# Where does Panther save its SAFE_OS minidumps?

Tags: windows-10, winpe

I'm trying to debug a (likely) driver crash during a Windows 10 feature update ("extend" code 0x2000D). The log (abbreviated since it's on a different machine) says

```
FatalError [0x090001] PANTHR Exception (code 0xE06D7363: <unknown>) occurred at ...
Minidump attached (69263 bytes) to diagerr.xml and X:\Windows\Panther\UnattendedGC\mndE39.diagerr.mdmp.
```

I can't see nothing attached to any diagerr.xml, nor do I have an `X:` drive mounted on this machine. Nor is there any `UnattendedGC` dir anywhere on the machine.

There's nothing in `%WINDIR%\Panther` or in `%WINDIR%\Minidump`. So where does Panther actually save those (SAFE_OS phase) minidumps??

I'm guessing the answer is "nowhere" since the [docs say](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/manufacture/desktop/deployment-troubleshooting-and-log-files)

> Because you are creating a new installation, the hard drive is not initially available, so Windows Setup writes logs into memory, specifically in a Windows PE session (X:\Windows). After the hard drive is formatted, Setup continues logging directly onto the new hard drive (C:\Windows). Log files created during the Windows PE session are temporary.

So `X:` seems to be a RAM drive that doesn't get copied somewhere else.

Comment: Logs can be found in C:\$Windows.~WS\Sources\Panther

Comment: @Moab: well, yes, that's where I've quoted `setuperr.log` from. That didn't help finding out which PE driver is crashing. The minidump is not there though.

Comment: Apparently WinPE is not actually configured to save those by default, so the message that it did save it is misleading. I found some instructions how to enable it https://deploymentresearch.com/debugging-bsod-in-winpe/ I have yet to try those.