# Windows 10 1709 Won't Upgrade / DISM Errors

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-upgrade, dism, sfc

I am trying to install a more current version of Windows 10 but everything I have tried has failed. I don't know if problems with `sfc /scannow` and `DISM` are related but the latter is also problematic. I ran `chkdsk /f /r` before attempting `sfc` and `DISM`.

### What I Have Tried

---

1. From Windows Update, version 1803
2. From Windows Update, version 1903
3. From Windows Update, version 21H2
4. From a USB created by Windows Media Creator, version 22H2

---

### Windows Image Repair Attempts

1. `SFC /scannow` returns the error:

   Windows Resource Protection found corrupt files but was unable to fix some
   of them. Details are included in the CBS.Log windir\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. For
   example C:\Windows\Logs\CBS\CBS.log. Note that logging is currently not
   supported in offline servicing scenarios.
2. `DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth` returns the error:

   Error: 0x800f081f

   The source files could not be found.
   Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the
   feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

   The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
3. `DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth /source:D:\install.wim` (from 22H2 iso) returns the error:

   Error: 0x800f081f

   The source files could not be found.
   Use the "Source" option to specify the location of the files that are required to restore the
   feature. For more information on specifying a source location, see
   http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=243077.

   The DISM log file can be found at C:\Windows\Logs\DISM\dism.log
4. `Dism.exe /Online /Cleanup-Image /AnalyzeComponentStore` returns

   Component Store (WinSxS) information:

   Windows Explorer Reported Size of Component Store : 9.42 GB

   Actual Size of Component Store : 9.09 GB

   ```
   Shared with Windows : 6.42 GB
   Backups and Disabled Features : 2.41 GB
   Cache and Temporary Data : 252.40 MB
   ```

   Date of Last Cleanup : 2023-04-29 09:57:40

   Number of Reclaimable Packages : 0
   Component Store Cleanup Recommended : No

   The operation completed successfully.

---

### Additional Information

I attempted to remedy my problems using the following guide ([guide](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/win-11-22h2-windows-update-repeatedly-trying-to/6fa4c600-42ce-4ffb-a3c2-dbba7e49307e)):

```
net stop bits
net stop wuauserv
net stop appidsvc
net stop cryptsvc
Del "%ALLUSERSPROFILE%\Application Data\Microsoft\Network\Downloader\*.*"
rmdir %systemroot%\SoftwareDistribution /S /Q
rmdir %systemroot%\system32\catroot2 /S /Q
regsvr32.exe /s atl.dll
regsvr32.exe /s urlmon.dll
regsvr32.exe /s mshtml.dll
netsh winsock reset
netsh winsock reset proxy
net start bits
net start wuauserv
net start appidsvc
net start cryptsvc
```

In doing this, I discovered that `appidsvc` is not running and will not run because of a bad digital signature. I am not sure if this contributes to the problem or not

---

Additionally, in the CBS log, I found the following appear multiple times (which appear to be different `sfc /scannow` sessions):

```
00005f53 [SR] Repairing 4 components
00005f54 [SR] Beginning Verify and Repair transaction
00005f57 [SR] Cannot verify component files for Microsoft-Hyper-V-Drivers-Hypervisor, version 10.0.16299.1087, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, manifest is damaged (true)
00005f5a [SR] Cannot verify component files for Microsoft-Hyper-V-3dVideo, version 10.0.16299.726, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, manifest is damaged (true)
00005f5d [SR] Cannot verify component files for Microsoft-OneCore-IsolatedUserMode-Common, version 10.0.16299.1059, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, manifest is damaged (true)
00005f60 [SR] Cannot verify component files for Microsoft-OneCore-IsolatedUserMode-Kernel, version 10.0.16299.699, arch amd64, nonSxS, pkt {l:8 b:31bf3856ad364e35}, manifest is damaged (true)
00005f61 [SR] Repair complete
00005f76 [SR] Committing transaction
00005f7b [SR] Verify and Repair Transaction completed. All files and registry keys listed in this transaction  have been successfully repaired
```

Upon seeing this, I figured I would try to remove Hyper-V to see what difference if any it would make. I received the following error when attempting to do so: `The component store has been corrupted. Error 0x80073712`

---

### Additional Information

After trying to repair with an in-place "upgrade" of the same version, I received the following error. I am presently trying troubleshooting with guides I am finding online. I will report any new information as it comes.

```
0x80070004 – 0x3000D
The installation failed in the FIRST_BOOT phase with an error during 
MIGRATE_DATE operation.
```

---

### Update

I found a `setuperr.log` in `C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback`. Here are its contents:

```
Error SP CSetupPlatformOSSwitchCheckpoint::Rollback: Deleting of "C:\Windows.old" directory failed.[gle=0x00000091]
Error IBSLIB OSRollbackService::CBootFilesRestoreCheckpoint::Rollback: Failed to create WinPE rollback directory: C:\$WINDOWS.~BT\Sources\Rollback\WinPE[gle=0x000000b7]
```

The file `setupact.log` has a lot of entries similar to the following:

```
 Warning SP SPMoveFileWithShortName: Failed to move \\?\c:\Windows\INF\3ware.PNF to \\?\c:\Windows.old\Windows\INF\3ware.PNF, error: 0x00000002
```

---

### Information I didn't realize was important at the time

I had changed the `Expandable String Value` `ProfilesDirectory` in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` to a location other than the default.

Comment: You have logs to check - that's the next step. Note that CBS logs are additive, same file covers all attempts right back. You can thin the data using `findstr /c:"[SR]" %windir%\Logs\CBS\CBS.log >"%userprofile%\Desktop\sfcdetails.txt"` which will save the errors to a new file on your desktop.

Comment: Perhaps you should first attempt to do an in-place repair install of your *current* Windows version - which is what?

Comment: You will have to parse the logs and provide the relevant information required to diagnose your issue. Disable Developer Mode[.](https://superuser.com/questions/1407284/cannot-seem-to-get-build-1809-update-installed-on-windows-10/1408627#1408627) The error you received is more than likely caused by it being enabled.

Comment: @harrymc - They are running 1709.

Comment: We also require SetupErr.log

Comment: It is not in developer mode and the SetupErr.log is empty

Comment: Also, I would try an in-place repair but I cannot find a download for version 1709

Comment: [1709](https://uupdump.net/selectlang.php?id=739e1800-9b70-4503-84f0-2b1ba73bfbdc). It’s indirectly directly from Microsoft

Comment: Worth pointing out. You have massive system corruption if your unable to install or uninstall optional Windows Features.

Comment: @Brian - `0x80070004 – 0x3000D` is associated with attempting to migrate user profile data for an invalid user profile. The log file has more details.  We need the relevant information from the log file to determine which profile is invalid.  SetupErr.log should be the file, but you said it was empty, which is odd to say the least[.](https://superuser.com/questions/946836/how-to-resolve-windows-10-installation-error-first-boot-migrate-data)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, be sure to change the `ProfilesDirectory` value in `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList` to the default `%SystemRoot%\Users`.

Next, attempt to do an in-place repair install of your
current Windows version, which is apparently Windows 10 1709.

You should download the ISO for this version, open it up and run `setup.exe`.
This is described in detail in the article
[How to Do a Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

If this fails, your setup is in a too-bad shape to be recovered,
so you will need to install the latest version of Windows 10 from scratch.

Getting an ISO for version 1709 is not easy, since Microsoft doesn't
cooperate. I list below one source that I have found. Remember that
this ISO is about 4 GB in size, so you should look for a fast download.

[Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) can create bootable USB, but also has
a repository of old ISO versions.
See the article
[How to download older ISO versions of Windows 10](https://pureinfotech.com/download-older-iso-windows-10/).
Rufus is a safe site.

Comment: @Brian - Be sure you edit your question instead of submitting a temporary comment. Only editing question will notify users.