# How can I repair Windows 10 corrupted files while the DISM command doesn't work?

Tags: windows-10, window, filesystem-corruption, dism

Recently My Windows 10 run into various blue screen error and I tried to fix them somehow and after restarting the machine many times and playing with machine Boot options it finally revived.

But now windows 10 can't install any update (and some software) and after downloading the updates, it faces problems during installation.

So I tried to check the health of the system using the `Dism` command. But that failed. `sfc /scannow` doesn't work either. Here are the result of `Dism` command for `ScanHealth` and `RestoreHealth`:

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
    
    Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
    Version: 10.0.19041.844
    
    Image Version: 10.0.19045.3448
    
    [==                         4.9%                           ]
    Error: 14098
    
    The component store has been corrupted.
    
    The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

```
    C:\WINDOWS\system32>Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
    
    Deployment Image Servicing and Management tool
    Version: 10.0.19041.844
    
    Image Version: 10.0.19045.3448
    
    [==                         3.8%                           ]
    Error: 14098
    
    The component store has been corrupted.
    
    The DISM log file can be found at C:\WINDOWS\Logs\DISM\dism.log
```

Apparently, the file corruption is so deep and fundamental, and I think it is impossible to repair the operating system through OS itself. So I think the only option is to use a bootable USB (except of course to reinstall Windows). I want to be very careful at this point so I don't lose any data.

**Question:** Can someone show me (step by step) how can I repair the windows 10 through Bootable USB and CMD?

**P.s.**

1. I have already created a system restore point.
2. I have already created a bootable USB for Windows 10 using Rufus.

Answer (score 0):

I've reinstalled the Windows 10 with keeping user data option as explained in [this tutorial](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) That I've found it with help of [this post.](https://superuser.com/a/1781535/1073810)

[image]